# lspci does not show graphic cards

Tags: nvidia-geforce

My rig contains 2 GTX 1080 TI 11 GB cards on MSI Tomhawk X299 AC motherboard, Intel i9 7900 processor.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and also Nvidia Drivers (nvidia-384) as recommended in "Software & Updates" --> "Additional Drivers" screen.

When I run "lspci | grep NVidia" command. I get response as shown in attached image. I was expecting output with make/model of both cards (eg. Geforce GTX 1080 Ti...). Attached a image I pulled from web that shows Titan X as output.

what is wrong here, requesting help please

[image: [enter image description here][2] imgur.com/A1otC.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

`lspci | grep NVidia` is a wrong command. There is no `NVidia` in `lspci` output. That is the reason you get an empty output.

`lspci | grep NVIDIA` could show your adapter.

Run `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`, or `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'` to see your adapters.

Answer (score 1):

I have a RTX 3080 mobile and running `lspci | grep nvidia` returned nothing.

What seemed to work was using `lspci | grep -i nvidia` instead. Which would give me

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB] (rev a1)
0000:01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```